# Storing user-inputted strings into a string array in c?

Tags: c

Fairly new to C, I am trying to read a file of multiple words using bash indirection, and put the words into a string array. The end of the file is marked with a -1.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void init(char* words[]);

int main(int argc,char *argv[]){
    char* words[400000];
    init(words);
    int i = 0;
    do{
        printf("%s",words[i]);
        i++;
    }while(!strcmp(words[i],"-1"));
}
void init(char* words[]){ // initializes array
    int i = 0;
    do{
        fgets(words[i],1024,stdin);
        i++;
    }while(!strcmp(words[i],"-1"));
}
```

This gives me a segmentation fault, if any other information is needed I'm more than happy to provide it.

Comment: You haven't provided a place for `fgets` to put the input.  Memory doesn't allocate itself.

Comment: `char* words[400000]` creates 400000 _pointers_ pointing to nowhere. You have to allocate memory to them before you read in strings to random locations pointed to by those pointers

Comment: David Reichert, What C compiler are you using?

Comment: @chux I'm using GCC

Comment: Try `gcc  -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -c ...` for quick informative feedback.  (Warnings) Faster than posting here.

Comment: You're never checking the return value of `fgets` either. And even then the `fgets` line will have the embedded newline.

Comment: And, did you try google first, this is asked almost daily (read words into array in C)

Comment: Change `char* words[400000];` into `char words[400000][1024];` for a quick fix.

Answer (score 0):

If I guessed correctly, '400000' means the max lines the user can input. But the default size of stack on Windows OS is 1M, sizeof(void*) * 400000 = 1,600,000...

The other thing is that you have not allocated memory for every line.

So, I try to correct your code like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_LINE 4000  // '400000' is really too big!

void init(char* words[]);

int main(int argc,char *argv[]){
    char* words[MAX_LINE];
    memset(words, 0 , sizeof(words));
    init(words);
    int i = 0;
    do{
        printf("%s",words[i]);
        delete words[i];
        words[i] = nullptr;
        i++;
    }while(!strcmp(words[i],"-1"));
}
void init(char* words[]){ // initializes array
    int maxLen = 1024;
    int i = 0;
    do{
        words[i] = new char[maxLen];
        memset(words[i], 0, maxLen);
        fgets(words[i], maxLen, stdin);
        i++;
    }while(!strcmp(words[i],"-1") && i < MAX_LINE);
}
```

Comment: `new char[maxLen];` - this is invalid expression in C. The question is about C, not C++.

Comment: @KamilCuk You are right, change new/delete to malloc/free to fix the C requirements pls.